# Spring Boot - will the executable jar created with one version compatible with the future releases?

Tags: spring-boot

When I look at the sample executable jar, I can see a no. of dependent jars in BOOT-INF/lib, most of them have the version no. in the file name. For example - jackson-annotations-2.8.1.jar

If a later release of Spring Boot starts packaging the next version of jackson-annotations.jar, do I have a way to work with the executable jar created with the previous version (other than re-creating the jar)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The executable jar is self contained and has all of the components required so it stands by itself.  This means that future upgrades have no impact on jars you have already created.  If you create new jars with future versions they may contain their own updated dependencies but your old jars will still work as is.  Like your other question this link http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html is a good reference on the executable jar.

Comment: Thank you Rob Baily